# Relative paths in WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, image, visual-studio, relative-path

I'm writing this WPF application in VS2013 and I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert my absolute paths into relative paths.

The app involves changing the grid backround when certain actions happen. I currently go about it like this:

```
ImageBrush b1 = new ImageBrush();
b1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\spectre\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\eGym v2\eGym v1\eGym v1\resources\example.jpg"));
grid1.Background = b1;
```

I'm trying to figure out how turn that absolute path into a relative path without changing too much of how the program is structured but even after looking around for a few hours now I cannot seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach saves me in WPF applications which use `Prism`, `MVVM Light`:

```
var myBrush = new ImageBrush();
var image = new Image{
     Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourApplicationName;component/Images/example.jpg"))};
myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
grid1.Background = myBrush;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image to your solution and reference it like this:

```
b1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\Image\example.jpg"));
```